# How do i disable unused rows of UITableView (Swift)?

Tags: swift, uitableview

When it comes to creating a dynamic type table view in a storyboard, it automatically fills up the table with rows.

How would i disable the red lined section (unused rows yet) of the image?

[image: Showing which rows i want to remove]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method from `UITableViewDataSource`, like so

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellId", for: indexPath)
    if indexPath.section == DISABLED_SECTION_INDEX {
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    } else {
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Or without if statement

```
cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = indexPath.section != DISABLED_SECTION_INDEX
```